# Generic solution/pattern for routing and views/forms with rich many to many associations (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

starting with Rails 4 I struggle at the moment with a common CRUD pattern. Found some resources but just don't get it.

Lets assume a product model, a supplier model and rich many to many association for prices. A given product is sold by many suppliers with different prices. Each supplier sells many products. The name of the rich many to many join model is "costprices". This ends up in the following three models.

### Models

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :costprices
    has_many :suppliers, through: :costprices
end

class Supplier < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :costprices
    has_many :products, through: :costprices
end

class Costprice < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :product
    belongs_to :supplier
end
```

A supplier offers hundreds or thousands of products. A product is offered from one or some (two, three, four) suppliers. The natural way for me seems to include an "add a supplier with his cost price" feature to some product form or, as I do here, to the product show page. This page could look something like this:

### products/show view

```
<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @product.name %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(@product) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', products_path %>

<!-- List all suppiers offering this product -->
<table>
  <% @product.costprices.each do |cp| %>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <%= link_to edit_product_costprice_path(cp, @product) do %>
          EDIT
        <% end %>
      </td>
      <td>
        <%= link_to product_costprice_path(cp, @product) do %>
          SHOW
        <% end %>
      </td>
      <td><%= cp.supplier.name %></td>
      <td><%= number_to_currency(cp.price) %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>

<%= link_to new_product_costprice_path(@product) do %>
  NEW
<% end %>
```

### costprices/new view (_form.html.erb)

Used by new and edit. With new, this still will not work. Have to add some logic for adding the supplier id. This works fine with edit and updates the the price correctly.

```
<%= form_for [@product, @costprice] do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :price %><br>
    <%= f.text_field 'price', :value => number_to_currency(@costprice.price) %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The link_to helpers assume this nested resources:

### routes.rb

```
  resources :suppliers
  resources :products do
    resources :costprices
  end
```

At this point, everything works well, except the "NEW" action. It is possible to click the SHOW action and the EDIT action. Clicking the NEW action results in a "undefined method *costprices_path*" error.

### Error description

> Showing /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views/costprices/_form.html.erb where 
>   line #1 raised: undefined method `costprices_path' for #<#:0x007f763dca5160>
>
> Extracted source (around line #1):

```
<%= form_for [@product, @costprice] do |f| %>
```

I do understand, that this resources do not generate a method *costprices_path*. But they generate a method *new_product_costprice_path (product_id)* and shouldn't be called this method clicking to new?
The URL by the way seems ok to me */products/1/costprices/new*

Mainly I'm interested at the explanation of this error and the correct solution. I headed this post with a "generic solution/pattern". Beside this error, I'm still not sure how to design a comfortable user interface (forms) addressing rich many-to-many associations / nested forms. If someone has good links addressing this kind of patterns, please share them.

### New action inside costprice_controller

```
def new
  @costprice = Costprice.new
end
```

Comment: Can you paste `new` view for the `CostPrice`?

Comment: View `_form.html.erb` is ok, where in the code _undefined method costprices_path_ exception is thrown?

Comment: Of course. Should have included the complete error description. Done .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wayne took me to the right direction. Should have posted all my source code.

In the `costprices_controller` I forgot to set the product for the new action.

Wrong: `before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]`

Correct: `before_action :set_product, only: [:new, :show, :edit, :update, :destroy]`

### What did I (new to Rails) learn from this exercise?

Do not blindly rely on the "rails magic" until you really understand all behind the scene. That's the heavy part of learning rails. Hopefully (I'm still not their) afterwards it is a lot fun relying on this "magic" to save a lot of time writing boilerplate lines of code again and again.

First, I did not even know which information is important to identify the problem. So I had to edit three or four times this post supplying missing information. That means, I had some misconception of rails routing. I assumed too much "magic" behind the scene. I thought the url will be analysed and somehow magically will call the correct named route. That's only halfway correct. `<%= form_for [@product, @costprice] do |f| %>` is no real magic and is essentially responsible for calling the correct named route (it is not the url). If `@product` is not set (no one sets @product for me, I had to do this in the controller) this construct equals to `<%= form_for [@costprice do] |f| %>` which results in an invalid call to the named route `costprices_path`, which of course does not exist.

Comment: Right, +1 for Waine. This path is required for the form when `@product` is nil, but doesn't result from the routing definition..

Answer (score 1):

This bug might be caused from `new.html.erb`or new action from your controller, check if you added `costprices_path` into your `new.html.erb` or `redirect_to @costprices` inside your new action.

If you're not familiar with m-to-m form, you can try [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form), it's very easy to use because it will handle m-to-m for you, check out `f.association` from simple_form.

Comment: Thanks Wayne. Did nothing beside setting `@costprice` in the controller action. See updated post. Didn't call `costprices_path` explicitly. `costprices_path` gets called implicitly here `<%= form_for [@product, @costprice] do |f| %>` in the new form `/app/views/costprices/_form.html.erb`